# Open dialog and display arraylist in textview

Tags: android, arraylist, dialog, android-dialogfragment

Ok, one simple question:  I have an arraylist in the main activity.  When the user clicks one button, I have it open a dialog where the user can enter name, phone number and email address, and when they click the dialog button "Add Contact", their input is stored in the aforementioned arraylist.  How do I get it to display in a second dialog(i.e. in a textview, etc.)?

My code for MainActivity.java:
    package com.example.java2midterm_lefelhocz;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Button btnAdd;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Button btnView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void btnAddOnClick(View v){
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DialogFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Add A Contact");

}
ArrayList <String>contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
public void btnViewOnClick(View v){
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DialogFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "View Contacts");


}
}
```

AddContactsDialog:
    package com.example.java2midterm_lefelhocz;

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.*;

public class AddContactDialog extends DialogFragment {
private EditText txtName;
private EditText txtPhone;
    private EditText txtEmail;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public AlertDialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_contacts, null));
    builder.setTitle("Add A Contact");
    builder.setPositiveButton("AddContact", new      DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            MainActivity ma = (MainActivity)getActivity();
            txtName = (EditText)AddContactDialog.this.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            txtPhone =     (EditText)AddContactDialog.this.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
            txtEmail =     (EditText)AddContactDialog.this.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
            ma.contacts.add(txtName.getText().toString());
            ma.contacts.add(txtPhone.getText().toString());
            ma.contacts.add(txtEmail.getText().toString());

        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}

}
```

Finally, ViewContacts.java:

package com.example.java2midterm_lefelhocz;

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.*;

public class ViewContacts extends DialogFragment {

private TextView txtContacts;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public AlertDialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());     


    inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();      


    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_contacts, null));
    builder.setTitle("Contacts");




    return builder.create();
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is the problem with the AddContactDialog or a "second dialog"?  If you need help with adding post the code related to `ma.contacts`, if you need help with ViewContacts describe the problem, what you want, and post the relevant code please. (You posted AddContactDialog twice...)

Comment: I can correctly store user input, I just need to display it in a dialog called ViewContacts.java

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass `contacts` in a Bundle with:

```
newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then read them with `getArguments()` in your Fragment. Or you can read `contacts` the same way you read it in AddContactsDialog as a static variable.  Using `public` variables is convenient but generally considered unsafe, the preferred methods are to use getters / setters and other ways of passing data indirectly (like in a Bundle).

You can display these contacts in your Dialog in numerous ways the most basic is [`setItems()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setItems%28java.lang.CharSequence%5b%5d,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29):

```
OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Log.v("Dialog List", "You clicked item " + which);
    }
};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());     
builder.setTitle("Contacts");
builder.setItems(MainActivity.contacts, dialogClickListener);
return builder.create();
```

Comment: I did the setItems, but it says that dialogClickListener cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: Yes, you need write a DialogInterface.OnClickListener to specify what you want to happen when an item is clicked.  I can write a superficial one if you want as a demonstration.

Comment: Ok, I'm using the setItems, but it apparently wants me to change the arraylist from string to int.  I don't want to do that.

Comment: Printing an entire array in one TextView will be very ugly, I recommend keeping `setItems()` or inflating your own ListView. You are right that you don't want to convert `contacts` to an integer, that is a different method with the same name. I forgot to convert the List to a primitive array, use `builder.setItems(MainActivity.contacts.toArray(new String[] {}), dialogClickListener);`. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ok, now it's asking me "Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer".

Comment: Add `{}` to make `new String[] {}`.

Comment: Ok, for some reason, it only opens the ViewContacts dialog, as if it were the main activity.

Comment: You are calling `DialogFragment newFragment = new DialogFragment();` in both OnClickListeners, but you want different subclasses so use the appropriate class. For instance: `AddContactDialog newFragment = new AddContactDialog();`